# In c, how to convert L"ñ" to wchar_t and other var; equivalent, like this: ->Lmyvar

Tags: c, algorithm, hex

I have a problem in the following code:

```c
int convert_to_opcodes(wchar_t *parts) {
wchar_t caracter[1];
wcscpy(caracter, parts);
return (int)caracter[0];
};
int main(void) {
wchar_t *text1=L"ñ";
printf("Opcode: %x\n",convert_to_opcodes(text1));

return 0;
}
```

This code found but I want to give a or convert L"ñ" to a argv[1] or other var equivalent:

```c
int convert_to_opcodes(wchar_t *parts) {
wchar_t caracter[1];
wcscpy(caracter, parts);
return (int)caracter[0];
};
int main(void) {
char *example="ñ"
wchar_t *text1=example;
printf("Opcode: %x\n",convert_to_opcodes(text1));

return 0;
}
```

Question:

How do I get the opcode of a character from A-Z0-1 and the special character like "ñ,%$?" For example?

What I hope to get are the opcodes of for example "ñ"=f1 and so on with each character

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it doesn't exist, try the first code I provide where the wchar_t is encoded with a (wide character) L"ñ", the result is f1, that is 0xf1: wchar_t *text1=L"ñ";

Comment: 1) The first snippet is jsut a really complicated way of doing `printf( "%x\n", (unsigned)text1[0] )`.  2) The first snippet does not perform any conversion. You *started* with decoded text. 3) See the comment that replaced the one to which you replied, which does provide a means of decoding.

Comment: Yes but, how I convert:
wchar_t *text1=L"ñ";
 printf( "%x\n", (unsigned)text1[0]);

like this:
wchar_t *text1=argv[1]; //equivalent without the L
 printf( "%x\n", (unsigned)text1[0]);

and get the same:
f1

Comment: I try with: wcstombs, mbrtowc and mbtowc and I get "c3" of "ñ", not f1

Comment: @MrK in the first snippet: "ñ" is coded in ISO-8859-1 and equals 0xf1, in the second one: it's in UTF8 0xc3b1. For which coding do you want to get opcodes? (it needs to be converted from one encoding to another if they are not equal)

Answer (score 1):

An "opcode" is a CPU instruction. I think you mean "Unicode Code Point".

One can refer to converting the text from encoded form to a wide string as decoding it, and it can be done using [`mbrtowc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbrtowc).<sup>[1]</sup>

You didn't specify the encoding, so I assumed UTF-8.

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main( void ) {
   setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8" );  // Converting from UTF-8?

   const char *text_utf8 = "ñ";
   size_t remaining = strlen( text_utf8 );

   mbstate_t state;
   memset( &state, 0, sizeof( state ) );

   while ( remaining ) {
      wchar_t ucp;
      size_t rv = mbrtowc( &ucp, text_utf8, remaining, &state );

      if ( rv == 0 )            // NUL encountered.
         break;
      if ( rv == (size_t)-2 )   // Incomplete sequence encountered.
         break;
      if ( rv == (size_t)-1 )   // Other error encountered.
         break;

      encoded_text += rv;
      remaining    -= rv;

      printf( "U+%06lX\n", (unsigned long)ucp );
   }
}
```

```
U+0000F1
```

---

1. Note that the example on the linked page is incorrect/incomplete since it doesn't take errors into consideration. `(size_t)-2` and `(size_t)-1` are both larger than 0.